# Is $f:A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous in $A \times B$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

Consider $f:A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$

$A \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is compact.

$B \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is open.

If we fix a point $P_B \in B$, $f$ varies continuous in $A$

If we fix a point $P_A \in A$, $f$ is constant in $B$

Then:

is $f:A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous in $A \times B$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Does there exist a function $g:A \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(a, b) = g(a)$ for all $(a, b) \in A\times B?$
If yes, is this $g$ continuous (on $A$)?
If yes, what can we conclude about the continuity of $f$ on $A \times B?$

---

Elaborating on part III:

We show that $f$ is continuous at an arbitrary $(a, b) \in A \times B$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. By continuity of $g$, we see that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|g(a) - g(x)| < \delta$ whenever $\|x - a\| < \delta$ and $x \in A$.

Now, note that given any $(x, y) \in A\times B$, we have
$$\|(a, b) - (x, y)\| \ge \|a - x\|.$$

Thus, if $\|(a, b) - (x, y)\| < \delta$, then $\|a - x\| < \delta$ which gives us that
$$|f(a, b) - f(x, y)| = |g(a) - g(x)| < \epsilon.$$

This completes our proof.

Comment: Part I: Yes, since $f$ does not depend on $b$. $$\text{ }$$ Part II: Fix $b$. It is given $f$ varies continuously in $A$.$f=g$. Therefore $g$ varies continuously in $A$. $$\text{ }$$ Part III: I have no idea. Need another hint.

Comment: Great. What definition of continuity do you use? Are you aware of the following one: $$\;$$ A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open (in $X$) for every open subset $U$ of $Y$?

Comment: I have now added a more elaborate answer anyway. That uses the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. I felt that the open set definition might lead to more confusion if you're not familiar.